# Importing CSV with data.table::fread results in messy data

Tags: r, encoding, import, data.table

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\20170207")
data<-fread("HC TX FR 2017Feb4-2017Feb7CustomTransaction.csv",header = "auto",sep = ","
            ,encoding="unknown")
```

but this is the resulting messy data:

```
 date/heure num茅ro de versement
1: 6 f茅vr. 2017 03:25:18 UTC+00:00           6916873522
```

The file content is:

```
date/heure  numéro de versement
6 févr. 2017 03:25:18 UTC+00:00 6916873522
```

Comment: What do you get if you try `encoding = "UTF-8"`? Or `encoding = "Latin-1"`?